# Django NoArgsCommand gives NameError: name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python, django, redis, cron, django-celery

I am trying to make a custom command to run on my celery crontabs, which extracts data from my db, makes a list, and then dumps that information as a list in redis. This list will then be used by other workers.

However, I am getting a NameError, which I haven't been able to solve despite reading relevant stack and Google posts.

My code below:

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand, CommandError
from detail.models import SD
import redis

class Command(NoArgsCommand):

    help = 'Gathers the symbols from the database and generates a list for crontabs, saving to redis.'

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):

        all = SD.objects.all()

        data = []

        for info in all:
            data.append(info.symb)  

        r = redis.Redis()

        try:
            r.delete('allsymbols')
        except:
            pass

        for xyz in data: **<---- the NameError refers to this line**
            r.rpush('allsymbols', xyz)
```

**TRACEBACK**

```
File "C:\.....command.py", line 5, in <module>
class Command(NoArgsCommand):
File "C:\.....command.py", line 26, in Command
for xyz in data:
```

NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: It looks like you have mixed tabs and spaces, from the source of your post.

Comment: @jpic - that may be when I transposed it to the code block. i don't thin that's what's causing the error.

Comment: @jpic - actually one sec. that may be doing it. will confirm.

Comment: @jpic yup it worked! that's strange - i've never come across this before where spaces caused errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script contains mixed tabs and spaces.

You should rather use only spaces, as per [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but the choice is yours, as long as you use the same in all your scripts.